# Sencha app watch is not watching imported scss files

Tags: extjs, extjs6, sencha-cmd, extjs6-classic

I'm using the latest extjs 6 cmd and when I run >sencha app watch in my theme,  only var/src/ all.scss is being watched.  I'm importing some other sass files but changes are not picked up until I manually refresh the page.

Do I need to include every .scss in my package.json?

Comment: Could you post the content of your app.json ?

Comment: Sorry I'd rather not. What section are you looking at? Maybe I could add a snippet.

Comment: The "sass" config part. By `manually refresh page` you mean like you refresh the web page and the app watch is triggered ? Or you are not seeing the changes in your theme when you are doing changes in scss files directly in the browser without page refresh?

Comment: When I reload the browser, the changes can be seen.  But app watch never fires when I alter a sass file other than all.scss .

Comment: "var": [
            "sass/var/all.scss",
            "sass/var"
        ],

Comment: I see, that is normal that you have to refresh webpage, if you don't want that - you have to have fashion enabled (for live updates) https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/guides/fashion.html#fashion_-_using_live_updates

Comment: I do have live updates on all.scss but not on any other imported scss

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out. I was missing the toolkit name.  Wrong path sigh.
I needed to add the folder src or var. Works like a charm.

```
"src": [
            "${package.dir}/${toolkit.name}/sass/src",
]
```